# How Do You Clear The IRB Console?

Tags: ruby, irb

How do you clear the IRB console screen?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

On *Mac OS X* or *Linux* you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to clear the *IRB* screen.

Comment: `Ctrl+L` also works in gnome-terminal, but something more programmatic is `system 'clear'`

Comment: With zsh ctrl + L doesn't work, ctrl + K does. (Oh My ZSH to be specific)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand I tested on Oh My ZSH and only Ctrl + L worked

Comment: @fanaugen On MacOS, `cmd+k` will clear all within a terminal tap, if you use tmux to split area of the visual area, `ctrl+L` will do a better work.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Windows 10 as well, both on the Command Prompt and the [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) (running Ubuntu). In WSL, it pushes the prompt to the top (history still remains scrollable) but in Command Prompt, it wipes out all the history too.

Answer (score 62):

Throw this inside `%userprofile%\.irbrc` and you're good

```
def cls
  system('cls')
end
```

From [IRB clear screen on windows](http://snipplr.com/view/3055/irb-clear-screen-on-windows/).

Comment: I should clarify that this applies to Windows only.

Comment: `system('clear')` will also work on a Mac. It should be noted that this will leave `=> true` at the top of the console.

Comment: @anthropomorphic `system('clear') will work on almost every Unix/Unix-like system.

Comment: @enedil That's absolutely true, however many people don't know that OS X is a Unix-like system.

Comment: @anthropomorphic because it is **not**. OS X is certified Unix by Open Group.

Comment: @BenHoffstein - I do not care that this comment is going to get deleted THANK YOU DUDE THANK  YOU `+=` >9,000.   
This took entirely too long to find, relative to my normal stackoverflow expurrrrience.

Comment: @BenHoffstein You should put that clarification in the body of your post. And maybe note that for Mac OS its `system('clear')`

Answer (score 46):

On *nix boxes

```
`clear`
```

on Windows

```
system 'cls' # works
`cls` # does not work
```

on OSX

```
system 'clear' # works
`clear` # does not work
```

Comment: yeah this doesn't work. Have to do `system('clear')` or `Ctrl` + `L`

Comment: `system 'clear'` worked for me but I got `: command not found
 => false`

Comment: You can add an alias such as `clear` you your pryrc file for this. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> in *macOS* works great.

Answer (score 16):

On Ubuntu 11.10 system `clear` will mostly clear the irb window. You get a return `=> True` value printed.

A big mess of ugly text

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > system 'clear'
```

what ya get:

```
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 >
```

Answer (score 13):

Just discovered this today: in Pry (an IRB alternative), a line of input that begins with a `.` will be forwarded to the command shell. Which means on Mac & Linux, we can use:

```
. clear
```

And, on Windows (Command Prompt and Windows Terminal), we can use:

```
. cls
```

Source: [pry.github.io](https://pry.github.io)

Comment: I just tried this using raw irb under Ruby 2.0.0p481 on Windows and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. Seems it does not work in windows. But it surely does work in mac & Linux.

Comment: I like this answer the best. You don't have to modify anything and it's just shelling out. Simple to remember too. Btw, `. cls` should work on Windows.

Comment: I wonder which command would work with tmux. I think Ctrl + L is the one as thatway_3 says down below.

Answer (score 12):

In order to clear the screen just do:

```
puts "\e[H\e[2J"
```

P.S. This was tested on Linux.

Comment: This is just the output from `\`clear\``, and is equivalent to `puts %x(/usr/bin/clear)`.

Answer (score 11):

```
system 'clear'
```

Should work for rails 4.0 as well

Answer (score 9):

On Linux Mint 17 also you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
to clear the IRB screen.

Comment: Worked for Mac OS X.11.1 in the Terminal app

Comment: @thatway_3 - nice answer: how did you print the keyboard instructions on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 6):

```
puts `clear`
```

Clears the screen and then returns `=> nil` Tested on Mac OSX 10.6 Terminal and iTerm2.

Answer (score 6):

Method:
`def clear_screen
   if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32|win64|\.NET|windows|cygwin|mingw32/i
      system('cls')
    else
      system('clear')
   end
end`

Or in IRB you can use `system('clear')`

Answer (score 5):

In windows, using Rails 4,

```
system('cls')
```

worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Tons of good answers here, but I often remote into a linux box with Mintty from windows. Kudos to the above about using .irbrc, but came up with this:

```
def cls
  puts "\ec\e[3J"
end

def clear
  puts "\e[H\e[2Js"
end
```

This gives you the options for both the *nix 'clear' behavior and the Windows 'cls' behavior, which I often find more useful if I really want to nuke the buffer rather than just scrolling it out of view.

P.S. a similar variant also works in .bashrc:

```
alias cls='echo -e "\ec\e[3J"'
```

If anyone could find a way to actually map that to a keystroke, I'd love to hear it. I would really like to have something akin to cmd-k on osx that would work in Mintty.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following method to `~/.irbrc`:

```
def clear
  conf.return_format = ""
  system('clear')
end
```

`Cntrl-L` or `Cntrl-K`  work in regular console but I'm using tmux and those mess the screen up inside the tmux window.

The **conf.return_format** = "" takes the nil off the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Windows users simply try,

```
system 'cls'
```

OR

```
system('cls')
```

Looks like this in the IRB window,

```
irb(main):333:0> system 'cls'
irb(main):007:0> system('cls')
```

Did the trick for me in ruby 1.9.3. However the following commands did not work and returned `=> nil`,

```
system('clear')
system 'clear'
system `cls`       #using the backquotes below ESC Key in windows
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used this for executable files:

```
def clear
    system("cls") || system("clear") || puts("\e[H\e[2J")
end

clear
```

Answer (score 3):

```
system 'cls'
```

Works for me in Windows, with Ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a way to reset the tty with irb, since it wasn't printing newlines or showing what I typed somehow, only some output.

```
1.9.3-p125 :151 >   system 'reset'
```

finally did the trick for me!

Comment: simplify it using back ticks: `\`reset\``.

Comment: @the Tin Man - backticks don't always operate how you think, but ``reset`` should work fine

Comment: Backticks always work how I expect but then, I've been using them in various languages for years and years.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes what resembles a backtick may indeed be some other UTF-8 creature. Occasionally I fix "text" docs with upper and lower quotation marks that are actually != the ANSI/ASCII " character.  Like in commercial SRT files, where all hell breaks loose.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users:

If you create a bat file name c.bat whose contents are:

```
@echo off
cls
```

Then, in IRB, you can say:

```
system('c')
```

to clear the console. I just thought I would share because I thought that was pretty cool. Essentially anything in the path is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
->(a,b,c){x=a.method(b);a.send(c,b){send c,b,&x;false};print"\e[2J\e[H \e[D"}[irb_context,:echo?,:define_singleton_method]
```

This will fully clear your IRB screen, with no extra empty lines and “=> nil” stuff. Tested on Linux/Windows.

This one-liner could be expanded as:

```
lambda {
  original_echo = irb_context.method(:echo?)
  irb_context.send(:define_singleton_method, :echo?) {
    send :define_singleton_method, :echo?, &original_echo
    false
  }
  print "\e[2J\e[H \e[D"
}.call
```

This uses lots of tricks.

Firstly, irb will call `echo?` to check if the result should be printed. I saved the method, then redefined with a method which restores the defination but returns false so irb will not echo the result.

Secondly, I printed some ANSI control chars. `\e[2J` will clean the screen and `\e[H` will move the cursor to the upper left position of the screen. `\e[D` will print a space and then move back the cursor while this is a workaround for something strange on Windows.

Finally this is kind of not practical at all. Just smile ;)

Answer (score -3):

The backtick operator captures the output of the command and returns it

```
s = `cls`
puts s
```

would work better, I guess.

Comment: This fails: You get this

irb(main):004:0> `cls`
=> "\f"

Comment: @OrionEdwards @JesperE the first line showed me `"\f"` which is what you got and then `puts s` outputs this `♀` I wonder why?