# Ruby clear screen

Tags: ruby, terminal, ruby-1.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I clear the terminal in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170553/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-ruby)

How to clear the terminal screen in ruby?

```
puts "hello, what's your name?"
input = gets.chomp
<<clearscreen>>
puts "nice to meet you, #{input}"
```

Answer (score 13):

Not sure what you're asking exactly, but there are different ways to clear irb / terminal in this post: [How Do You Clear The IRB Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116593/how-do-you-clear-the-irb-console)

One that is intersting is

In order to clear the screen just do a

> `puts "\e[H\e[2J"`

Comment: I'n not sure that that's cross platform.

Comment: This is escape sequence. All terminals support it.

Comment: Doesn't work with in the DOS box of Win XP.

Comment: Works in iTerm2 3.0.15 on macOS 10.12.5 (16F73) using Bash 4.4.12(1)-release.